# Twilio Rest Api PHP - Machine Detection

Tags: php, rest, api, twilio, phone-call

I am trying to use the Twilio Rest Api to make an outgoing call from/to Germany.
Furthermore I want to use the MachineDetection Feature Twilio offers 
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection)
This is how I tried it, but it doesnt work.

```
   ...
      try {
        // Initiate a new outbound call
        $call = $client->account->calls->create(
          $toNumber, // Number to call.
          $fromNumber, // Twilio Number
          // URL Twilio will request when the call is answered.
          array(
            "url" => "http://pseudourl.com/manageCall.php",
            "MachineDetection" => "Enable"
          )
        );
        echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
   ...
```

In the manageCall.php file I expect to get the following, but I dont.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['AnsweredBy']) && $_REQUEST['AnsweredBy'] == "human") {
  ...
}
```

Can anyone help me out how to use the feature right?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio's answering machine detection currently supports calling to the US, Canada, United Kingdom, Netherlands, Finland and Sweden.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection) The documentation currently says that if you are looking to use AMD in another country, such as Germany, to please [contact support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they will add it to the backlog.